# Android API and Gradle version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new at developing Android apps. Currently, I am planning to do the API version upgrader  from API 25 to API 28. Is that necessary to upgrade the Gladle version as well? In my opinion it is needn't.

Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Some android studio versions require newer versions of gradle

Comment: if studio gives an error for updating gradle for specific version thn you have to do it because The Android Studio build system is based on Gradle, and the Android Gradle plugin adds several features that are specific to building Android apps. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: I suggest you ,if you had stable connection then always make up-to-date your android studio and gradle  because it will give many new features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mandatory. Update or not it's fully your choice. Gradle update or Sdk update they are not connected to each other directly. Sdk update gives you new different features, Gradle update gives you other different features. Those are different. But updating is always good. I suggest you to update Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is required. Some cases it is not. WHEN IT IS COMPATIBLE.
When moving 3 versions and ESPECIALLY when moving to the new AndroidX support and API 28 it is definitely required. Anyone who says it is not, has not done this upgrade yet.

Gradle plugins are written specifically to match the build tools, and while not every update is a breaking change between the two. It is recommended that you stay with compatible versions. They must be compatible. For example if you are moving to 28, you will be likely using the migration tool to migrate to androidx namespaces. This breaks a lot of code and requires a little TLC to get it back up and running.

Then your Gradle will need an extra properties file to know that children namespaces will not match and will cause conflicts. To fix this we add a gradle.properties file in project root.

**gradle.properties**

```
 android.enableJetifier=true
 android.useAndroidX=true
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m <--OPTIONAL Up to you, memory management
```

The AndroidX is for the latest 28 API
The Jetifier is for enabling transitive and direct dependencies to have an attempt at translating those into latest androidx compatibility compiling mode.

If you don't do these items, you will not get properly compiling on 28.

Kotlin Version 1.2.70 is where you want to be. As .71 has freezing issues.
Gradle. 3.3.0-alpha11 or you can do 3.4.0-alpha01. No one enjoys using alpha builds, but if you are moving into androidx and build tools 28, I recommend it otherwise you will fight compiling issues. Just keep an eye out for the stable release in the coming months.

Make sure you have the latest allprojects repos as well as they use jetpack now.
So in your parent project build.gradle include.

**PROJECT LEVEL build.gradle**

```
  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.70'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application Module level build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

        android {
           compileSdkVersion 28
           buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
etc.....//////

     dependencies {
        //Kotlin Compiler Libraries
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.25.3'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.25.3'

        //Android Google Libraries
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
        implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"

etc.....//////
```

Trust me when I tell you. I spent days battling the androidx updates to get into 28 early on. So if someone gives you compatible versions that match and play well together. Take it and run with it. I have done that for you above.

More info on migrating to 28 and and supporting new namespaces by Android.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

One of their most painful updates I've ever dealt with since version 1. So prepare for some annoyances ;).

Happy Coding.